# Retrieving Emails using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I need to duplicate an HTML Email with SSJS but in order to do that, firstly, I should get the content of the Email I want. I have written the code below but it doesn't work. The strange thing is the same code works for Data Extensions when I change ObjectType.

```
<script runat="server"> 

Platform.Load("core", "1");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "Email");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ID");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");

var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "Equals");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", "asgdsgsgsgsdgsg");

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var Result = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr,StatusAndRequestID);

if(Result != null) {

Write("It works");}

else { Write("It doesn't work");}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code for the SSJS Function `SetObjectProperty` inside the [reference doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAPISetObjectProperty.htm)s is actually related to your question. It looks like the properties require a prefix of `Email.` prior to each.

See snippet below:

```
// Set the columns
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.Name");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.ID");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.Subject");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.Status");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.CharacterSet");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Email.ContentCheckStatus");
```

I would also look into using [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm) for this and future SOAP API needs inside SSJS. It shortens your 'overhead' to the processing of your calls, making them more efficient and quicker.

> The legacy methods for accessing SOAP object data, including what is
>   used in the SSJS Core Library, are primarily wrappers around AMPScript
>   functions. Using legacy SSJS methods adds overhead to the processing
>   of the calls as the code translates the data between the different
>   language runtimes. The WSProxy object is native to the platform and
>   simpler to use than the SSJS methods. The object reduces overhead and
>   increases speed of your API calls. The object’s usage syntax is much
>   more JavaScript-like when compared to the existing platform functions.

Comment: Can it get Email.Campaign too? Email.CampaignName? @Gortonington

Comment: I do not see those as options inside the Documentation on the email object nor a describe of it. So I do not believe those are options to retrieve. If I am missing something, then yes. As long as the properties are retrievable, then they can be pulled using the above method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/email.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for WSProxy Retrieve (the better way to make SOAP API calls with SSJS):
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_advanced_retrieve.htm?search_text=for%20loop%20javascript

This is how you would write your code using WSProxy (and losing the `Platform.Load("core", "1");` call).  I tested this code, and you shouldn't need to prepend your property names with Email:

```
<script runat="server">
function Write(str) {
   Platform.Response.Write(str);
}

/*------------------------------------------*/

function Stringify(obj) {
   return Platform.Function.Stringify(obj);
}

/*------------------------------------------*/

var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); // Create WSProxy object

api.setClientId({ "ID": Platform.Function.AuthenticatedMemberID()}); // Set ClientID if you need to

var retrieveObject = 'Email'; // Set your object

var cols = ['Name','HTMLBody','CustomerKey','ID','ModifiedDate','CategoryID', 'Client.ID']; // Choose the properties you'd like the call to return

var filter = { 
    Property: "ID", 
    SimpleOperator: "equals", 
    Value: '123714'
};

var opts   = {}; // Set options, like number of results returned -- see docs
var props  = {QueryAllAccounts: false}; // Set properties like QueryAllAccounts -- see docs

var data = api.retrieve(retrieveObject, cols, filter, opts, props);

if (data['Status'] != 'OK'){
   Write('There was an error: '+data['Status']);
} else if (data['Results'].length == 0) {
   Write('No results were returned');
} else {
   Write('Here are my results!<br />'+Stringify(data).replace(/\n/g,"<br />\n")
}
</script>
```